# python flask: How to handle send_file on the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, savefiledialog

I generated an excel file server-side in situ from input given on the client side using xlwt and StringIO. Now I would like to send the file back to the client, so that s/he can save it (Ideally with a Save Dialog).

I am trying to do that with `send_file`, but as I am not very good with javascript/jquery/ajax, I do not actually know how to handle this on the client side. Based on the code below (gathered mostly from the flask homepage), could you give me a hint how to get there?

Thanks for your help!

Here's the code:

Please Note: The JS Code is triggered by a click event on a button. It works fine when passing json from client to server and back...

**Python**

```
import StringIO
import wordpuzzle # The code that creates the excel file

@app.route('/_create_wordsearch')
def create_wordsearch():

    wordlist = json.loads(request.args.get('wordlist'))

    # create a stringIO object
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    # Instantiate the PuzzleGrid class
    p = wordpuzzle.PuzzleGrid(wordlist)

    # Create the Puzzle
    p.main()

    # Create the xls file in memory
    p.output2excel(output)

    # Set back to start
    output.seek(0)

    # send back to client
    return send_file(output, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#create_btn").bind('click', function(){
        //Get all words from list
        var list = [];
        $("#wordlist option").each(function(){
            list.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_create_wordsearch', {
            wordlist: JSON.stringify(list)
        }, function(data){
            // What goes in here?
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't believe you can use JavaScript for this. You need to allow the browser to submit a form (most likely a POST) to `/_create_wordsearch` so that is can handle the file download.

Comment: @dirn: always a pity to hear that one's efforts went in the wrong direction and were for nothing ;)... well :(, I guess. How would I do it with POST? Can you link to a good code example?

Comment: You just need an HTML `form`.

Comment: @dirn: Do you have a good code example that uses flask and html? I am new to this and I cannot distinguish the good from the bad ones. I am alright with python. html/js/css webthingy not so much. I only ever find the python/flask side (tutorials and so on), but never really a whole example including html and maybe even js.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? I imagine your work is mostly done already. You'll just need to update your view to accept POSTs. The [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) has a section about HTTP methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a div on the page to use as a target:

```
<div id="exportdiv"></div>
```

Replace your $.getJSON call with code like this:

```
var url = $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_create_wordsearch';

// hide the div, write the form
$('#exportdiv').hide()
    .html('<form id="exportform" action="' + url + '" target="_blank" method="get">'
        + '<textarea name="wordlist">' + JSON.stringify(list) +'</textarea>'
        + '</form>');

// submit the form
$('#exportform').submit();
```

And on the server side, you will need to unescape the JSON.  I'm not certain if you can feed [Markup.unescape()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Markup.unescape) directly into json.loads but it will be something like:

```
wordlist = json.loads(Markup(request.args.get('wordlist')).unescape())
```